# JavaFX BarChart - series off main axis

Tags: java, javafx

Why are the bars off their center tick mark?  And why can’t I control the bar's size?

[image: -enter image description here]

```
public class DoubleSeriesBarChart extends Application {

    private BarChart<String, Number> chart;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        primaryStage.setTitle("BarChart Experiments");

        final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
        final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
        this.chart = new BarChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);
        this.chart.setAnimated(false);

        this.chart.setBarGap(0);
        this.chart.setCategoryGap(0);

        XYChart.Series series1 = new XYChart.Series();
        series1.setName("300");
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("A1", 25601.34));
        series1.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("A2", 20148.82));

        XYChart.Series series2 = new XYChart.Series();
        series2.setName("302.50");
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("B1", 57401.85));
        series2.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("B2", 41941.19));

        XYChart.Series series3 = new XYChart.Series();
        series3.setName("305");
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("C1", 45000.65));
        series3.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("C2", 44835.76));

        this.chart.getData().addAll(series1, series2, series3);

        VBox vbox = new VBox(this.chart);

        Scene scene = new Scene(vbox, 400, 600);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.setWidth(400);
        primaryStage.setHeight(600);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: [mcve] please .. what exactly do you expect?

Comment: Because you have three different `Series`, so it expects to draw three bars per category.

Comment: @Slaw ok that kind of makes sense, so is there any workaround?

Comment: Assuming no two `Series` will ever have data in the same category you could try a [`StackedBarChart`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.controls/javafx/scene/chart/StackedBarChart.html).

Comment: @Slaw i would rather have the bars side by side

Comment: The categories will still be side by side. Your example only has one series per category; a `StackedBarChart` only stacks the bars if there's at least _two_ series in one category.

Comment: let them have the same category .. that's what a barChart is meant to handle